# Magento 2 add new text filed at custom options section?

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options

How can I add a new text field in the custom options section in Magento 2  as shown in the screenshot below?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:
    I got the answer for the above question to add the text field by simply    editing the customOptions.php file

```
Location:vendor/magento/module- catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php
```

**step1**: Add your text field at line number:68

const FIELD_NEW_TEXT_NAME = 'new_text_field';

**step2**:Add the Children at line number:584,634

static::FIELD_NEW_TEXT_NAME => $this->getNewTextFieldConfig(41),

**step3**:Copy the Total function code of getMaxCharactersFieldConfig
  and Create the function at line number:936

by following code:

```
protected function getNewTextFieldConfig($sortOrder)
 {
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('New Text field'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::FIELD_NEW_TEXT_NAME,
                    'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'validation' => [
                        'validate-zero-or-greater' => true
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
  }
```

**step 4**:Created the respected columns for fields in database
  find the table name below:

catalog_product_option
   catalog_product_option_type_value

**Step 5**:clear the cache and check the out put.

Comment: I'm not able to get the custom option from $block->getOption(); if any idea?

Comment: While this may work, you really shouldn't edit core files.